# Como resolver problema de busca com palavras acentuadas

Tags: php, mysql

Fiz uma inserção de dados em uma tabela no meu banco de dados usando o comando `load` e os campos com acentuação ficaram corretos, como por exemplo `Sofá Nápoli`, mas ao alterar qualquer registro que contenha acento pelo meu painel de controle o registro enviado ao banco fica assim `Sof&aacute; N&aacute;poli`, a minha tabela está codificada como `utf8_general_ci`.
Quando faço uma busca em meu site pelo termo `Sofá Nápoli` o registro não é exibido.
O resgate da minha variável ao ser digitada no campo de busca está assim:

```
$_SESSION['s'] = addslashes($_REQUEST['s']);
$pesquisa = $_SESSION['s'];
$pesquisa = (strtolower($pesquisa));
```

Não consegui achar uma solução que desse certo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a função [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) antes de passar o nome para consulta ao banco de dados. A chamada será parecida com esta:

```
$string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
```

Comment: Olá @Dherik, obrigado pela ajuda, fiz a alteração mas o campo de busca agora fica com o termo assim "sofÃ¡ nÃ¡poli".

Comment: O que ocorre quando você usa: `$string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");`?

Comment: De igual modo o texto fica assim: sofÃ¡ nÃ¡poli

Comment: Vamos simplificar então. Qual o valor de varTitle quando faz: `var varTitle = html_entity_decode("Sof&aacute; N&aacute;poli");`?

Comment: Olá @Dherik, agora o texto fica correto: Sofá Nápoli

Answer (score 0):

Na hora que você for fazer a consulta no banco transforme as duas em caixa alta/baixa.

Exemplo:

```
Select * from where LOWER(campo) like LOWER($pesquisa)
```

Comment: Olá @Gerson Costa, obrigado pela dica, mas não resolveu o meu problema.