# Como decodificar entidades html (entity)?

Tags: php

Tenho uma *string* que me retorna do banco no seguinte formato:

> Recebido por estagi&aacute;rios do **projeto** Mem&oacute;ria

Gostaria de converte-la para o formato sem as marcações e conversões das acentuações, ficando desta forma:

> Recebido por estagiários do projeto Memória

Como eu devo fazer?

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Codificador e Decodificador de caracteres especiais em HTML](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91774/3635) e [Como resolver problema de busca com palavras acentuadas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57315/3635)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Para remover *entities* da *string*:

Basta usar a função `html_entity_decode`

```
$dec = html_entity_decode( 'Recebido por estagi&aacute;rios do projeto Mem&oacute;ria' );
```

Se precisar especificar um *charset*, use o terceiro parâmetro:

```
html_entity_decode( 'estagi&aacute;rios', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/FyTrYm)**.

Mais detalhes no manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.html-entity-decode.php

### Para remover *tags* da *string*:

Você tem a opção de remover as tags usando `strip_tags`

```
$dec = strip_tags( 'do <b>projeto<b>' );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/j1EYJP)**.

Mais detalhes no manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Muito obrigado deu certo.

Comment: Ótimo exemplo! +1